# How to prove this formula $ \sum_{k=2}^n k(k-1)\binom{k}{n} = n(n-1) \cdot 2^{n-2}$?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

$$ \sum_{k=2}^n k(k-1)\binom{k}{n} = n(n-1) \cdot 2^{n-2}$$

Comment: Did you mean $\binom{n}{k}$?

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Please share the question it duplicates.

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit combinatorial

Comment: @J.G. yeah, sorry

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit Thanks, yeah

Answer (score 2):

Observe that for all $ n\geq 2 $, $ k\in\left[\!\left[2,n\right]\!\right] $, we have : $$ k\left(k-1\right)\binom{n}{k}=n\left(n-1\right)\binom{n-2}{k-2} $$

Thus : \begin{aligned} \sum_{k=2}^{n}{k\left(k-1\right)\binom{n}{k}}&=n\left(n-1\right)\sum_{k=2}^{n}{\binom{n-2}{k-2}}\\ &=n\left(n-1\right)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}{\binom{n-2}{k}}\\ &=n\left(n-1\right)2^{n-2} \end{aligned}

Answer (score 0):

Hint: show that $k(k-1) \binom{n}{k}  = n(n-1) \binom{n-2}{k-2}$.